# Python crashes when trying to find duplicates in a very long list

Tags: python, list

I have a text file with model numbers (7 char each) on each line.
The file is about 30,000 lines long.

I am trying to only pick out models with duplicate entries, but Python crashes (freezes, not responding) when I run this code. I also need to know which lines the duplicates are on.

```
uniqueList = []
dupList = []
termList = open("terIDtest2.txt").readlines()
i = 0    
for i in range(len(termList)):
    line = termList[i].split()
    if line not in uniqueList:
        uniqueList.append(line)
    else:
        dupList.append(line)
    i += 1

print (dupList)
```

The first 5 lines of the text file are:

```
FL0881
IL1695
CA0496
NY4459
NJ0203
```

After reading the comments, I tried this:

```
termList = open("terIDtest2.txt")
i = 1
for line in termList:
    line.strip("\n")
    if line in errorDict:
        errorDict[line].append(i)
    else:
        errorDict[line] = [i]
    i += 1

for i, n in errorDict.items():
    print (str(i) + str(n))
```

Still won't ever finish running.

Comment: why not converting to `set`?

Comment: It's not "crashing", you're code is just extremely inefficient, because you are using a `list` as your container for unique objects. However, this makes your overall algorithm quadratic time since list object have linear-time search. Use a `set` for constant time search.

Comment: As an aside, `i += 1` is completely pointless. You are using `i` as the assignment target of the for-loop statement, so `i` will be immediately overwritten at the beginning of each iteration. You don't need `i=0` and `i +=1` at all. Better yet, you dont need `readlines`. Just *loop directly over your file object: `for line in f: ...`

Comment: I am using a list because eventually I will need to know the indices of the duplicate entries. Is there a better way to implement that?

Comment: How would your current approach give you the indices? It seems to me that if you you a `list` or a `set`, your approach to that would be exactly the same, only that a `set` would be the appropriate container, with a list being needlessly inefficient

Comment: I was going to add a line underneath the else statement to save "i" to another list.

Or could I use a dictionary and save each unique model number with their line number as the value, then print only keys with multiple values?

Comment: You don't actually need to *store* duplicates; you just need to *count* them. `lines = collections.Counter(map(str.split, open("...")))`, ignoring some niceties like ensuring the file is properly closed.

Comment: Then `dups = [line for line, count in lines.items() if count > 1]`

Comment: @jkim right, and how does using a `set` vs a `list` prevent you from doing that?

Comment: could you show the first 5 line of `terIDtest2.txt` so we can understand what you want?

Comment: You can edit your original post and add your text at the end. format it as you format the code

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to store each duplicate; storing one copy, along with the line numbers, is sufficient.

```
import collections

occurrences = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("terIDtest2.txt") as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        occurrences[line.strip()].append(line_number)

unique_list = [(s, lines[0]) for s, lines in occurrences.items() if len(lines) == 1]
duplicate_list = [(s, lines[1:]) for s, lines in occurrences.items() if len(lines) > 1]
```

or

```
unique_list = []
duplicate_list = []
for s, lines in occurrences.items():
    if len(lines) == 1:
        unique_list.append((s, lines[0]))
    else:
        duplicate_list.append((s, lines[1:]))
```

The duplicates are those elements of `lines` whose list has more than one element. The first unique occurrence appears on the first element of that list.

You can also use `lines` instead of `lines[1:]` if you need the line number of the first occurrence of the duplicate in `duplicate_list`.

Comment: Does this not still run into an extremely absurd run time like my code above as @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned?

Comment: That depends on what you do with `unique_list` and `duplicate_list`; *building* them in this way is efficient, as the `defaultdict` also has O(1) lookup times for a line read from the file.

Comment: I added some more code that I tried, still doesn't finish running.

Comment: Should be `line = line.strip("\n")`, but that won't cause any problem. Can you add some debugging output to the loop to get an idea of how fast (or slow) it's working?

Answer (score 0):

this is my code using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(int)
with open('C:/d2','r') as readObject:
    for line in readObject:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
        d[line] +=1

print(d)
```

DUPLICATES

```
for (k,v) in d.items():
    if(v>1):
        print(k,v)
```

UNIQUE

```
for (k,v) in d.items():
    if(v==1):
        print(k,v)
```

DATA

```
FL0881
IL1695
CA0496
NY4459
NJ0203
NY4459
NJ0203
FL0881
FL0881
FL0881
FL0881
FL0881
FL9999
```

DUPLICATES

```
FL0881 6
NY4459 2
NJ0203 2
```

UNIQUE

```
IL1695 1
CA0496 1
FL9999 1
```

#### UPDATE duplicate with line numbers

*you may need to adjust the line number since it starts from 0.

```
d1=defaultdict(list)
lineNumner=1
with open('C:/random/d2','r') as readObject:
    for line in readObject:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
        d1[line].append(lineNumner)
        lineNumner +=1

for (k,v) in d1.items():
    if (len(v) >1):
        print('Duplicated for {} happnes at lines: {}'.format(k,v))
```

RESULT

```
Duplicated for FL0881 happnes at lines: [1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Duplicated for NY4459 happnes at lines: [4, 6]
Duplicated for NJ0203 happnes at lines: [5, 7]
```

Comment: I was stupid and forgot to mention in the original question that I need to know what line number the duplicates of each model are.

Comment: I added some more code that I tried, but the code still doesn't ever stop running.